# SCons dependencies in SConstruct

Tags: build, dependencies, scons

During build I need to:

- compile multiple libraries, during which I:

  - compile two libraries in two steps

    - 1: to objects
    - 2: list objects and link them into static library
  - Build the rest normally to static libraries
- link the program

Libraries names are taken from building directory in SConscript.
Why adding dependency to SConscript(...) call result like that doesn't work: ?

```
a = SConscript( ... ) 
b = SConscript( ... )
Depends(a, b)
```

If not than how can I add dependency when libraries names are known only in SConscripts, and these are in Install(...) directory passed to SConsctipt?

Comment: Did you already have a look at the [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), especially chap. 14 "Hierarchical Builds"?

Comment: @dirkbaechle I've read it through at least once and have it open all the time. I wouldn't ask if I could find an answer.

Comment: Sure...what exactly do you return in your SConscripts? Can you strip down your problem to an MWE and post it here?

Comment: Are you providing some value via Return() in the SConscripts?  You shouldn't need to add the depends if the files/programs just depend on the libraries,etc being in the LIBPATH. SCons will figure it out. If it can't, likely you've done something wrong.

Comment: @dirkbaechle Thanks, I found out that I didn't Return a thing in one of scripts, why does it still add Dependency to non existent return value, should I post it as a bug?

Comment: @bdbaddog I'm returning StaticLib(...) value. I'm filling my LIBPATH with glob from my directory pointed by Install(...) in all SConscripts. That's why I think dependency matching would fail.

Comment: @pholat when you pass an empty list to the `Depends` method it shouldn't add a dependency. If you can show (MWE again) that this happens, please come to the User mailing list at scons-users@scons.org (see http://scons.org/lists.html) and present your findings there. It's the best place to discuss whether this is actually a bug or not. Please note that simply claiming SCons should have thrown an error on the empty list does *not* qualify, thanks.

Comment: @dirkbaechle It shouldn't but it doesn't notify any error in any way, in my opinion it's misleading behaviour - as I expected some kind of notification. Of course I'll write on mailing list with a fitting example.

Comment: LIBPATH should point at the directory. Not a the libraries. So Glob()'ing your  library directory is the wrong thing to do.  As Dirk said. You really need to provide a minimum working example for us (or anyone else) to help you.

Comment: @bdbaddog If my LIBPATH will point to the directory where libraries will be installed during compilation it will work fine even without using Depends(...)? As I have a few other notices I'm writting on SCons mailing list. Making cut in example take it's time too.

Comment: Yes. SCons will know that it's going to be put there and use that to order the compilation, library creation, installing it to a dir, then linking..